# Does anyone know how to change the color of text based on and updated value JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I Have a slider that has a number output associated with it. I am able to apply the color for all the number, but it doesn't change when the slider value goes to a different color range.

```js
document.body.addEventListener("change", color());

function color() {
  if (document.getElementById("strengthLevel").innerHTML < 31) {
    document.getElementById("outpu").style.color = "Green";
  } else if (document.getElementById("strengthLevel").innerHTML < 55) {
    document.getElementById("outpu").style.color = "Yellow";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("outpu").style.color = "Red";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group" oninput="outpu.value=strengthLevel.value, color()">

  <label for="strengthLevel">Caffeine Rating </label> <label> <output id="outpu">30</output></label>

  <input name="strength" id="strengthLevel" type="range" value="30">

</div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>

<button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>

</form>

</div>

</div>

<div class="panel panel-default">

  <div class="panel-body">

    <h4>Pending Orders:</h4>

    <div data-coffee-order="checklist">

    </div>

  </div>

</div>

</section>
```

I tired this code and I am only able to make the text green

Comment: please add revelant HTML [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I've converted your posted HTML into a running example, except that it can't run because you're missing the a lot of the opening elements, for example the `<section>` and `<form>`, which means that your reset button doesn't work (and neither does the submit, but you probably don't want that to work here, so you may want to change the `type` to `type="button"` for the demo code here). Please, as you've been kindly asked already, take some time to help us work with your problems, and post the relevant (albeit minimal, functioning) HTML in your question

Comment: Use `value` instaed of `innerHTML`

Comment: yup, just changing your `innerHTML` for `value` solves the entire problem

Comment: Should be: `document.body.addEventListener("change", color);` - **do not execute like** `document.body.addEventListener("change", color());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see in your example code, you're adding the change event listener to the body. Try to add it to your slider instead.

An example:

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" id="testSlider" />

<div id="testOutput">Test</div>

<script>
let testSlider = document.querySelector("#testSlider");
let testOutput = document.querySelector("#testOutput");

function changeColor() {
    let value = testSlider.value;
    let colorValue = "green";
    
    if(value < 30) { colorValue = "orange"; }
    if(value < 10) { colorValue = "red"; }

    testOutput.style.color = colorValue;
}

testSlider.addEventListener("change", changeColor);
</script>
```

Comment: Try to always use `const` instead of `let` when you have no plans in altering the associated value.

Comment: Also, use the `"input"` eventName for a better UI/UX.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I agree it could've been const in this case. I wasn't too sure what else functionality this function might have, so I've used let to not create an unwanted second issue that isn't connected to this example.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan the original code used a change event which is why I used it in here as well.